# oracle, select form a large table repeated

Tags: sql, oracle

I hava a table with **millions of records**.Each record keeps a user's browse hehavior    to an item.Like

```
>BrowseRecordTable  
>| ------------------------|   
>userid,itemid,operatetime
```

when give me an item id(itmeid1), now i want to find out **who browse this item also     browse**. 
Here is what i do :
①、select all the record from BrowseRecordTable where itemid = itemid1
②、for each record,get the userid(temp_userid),
    and then select the record from BrowseRecordTable where userid = temp_userid 
    in half hour.

when BrowseRecordTable is very large. There is some trouble.
if there is thousands of records of an itemid in ①
then i need to select from BrowseRecordTable Thousands times in ②

if there is a better way to accomplish my task ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a join like this?

```
select * from BrowseRecordTable where userid in (
  select userid from BrowseRecordTable where itemid=itemid1)
```